# Pointer to array vs pointer

Tags: c

I examined a lot question that asked in stackoverflow but ı didn't get exact answer of my question. Btw,my question is about C.

```
int a[10] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
int (*p)[10]; // ı know it is pointer to int array that consist of 10 elements.
int *d;

d = a;
p = &a; // it is array type

printf("*p = %p , p = %d", (void *)*p, (void*)p); // it prints same thing, start address of "a" array 
printf("*d = %p, d = %p",*d,d); // it prints a[0] and start address of a respectively.
```

I know already "p" is a array typed  but actually it is a pointer for array (it occupy 8 bytes in memory like "d" with address data in most of systems). When ı dereference "p", ı expect "a[0]". Someway compiler handle it and returns address data of "a" array. But why? Is this about standart or historically thing? Because ı didn't find any reason why compiler does that. It could be normally dereference it like as "d".

Comment: "*When ı dereference "p", ı expect "a[0]".*" -- why? You already know that `p` is a pointer to the whole array identified by `a`. Therefore, when you dereference it, that array is what you get, not one of its elements.  From that point, what happens is exactly the same as if you had used `a` instead of `*p` to refer to the array.

Comment: @JohnBollinger because of ı know that if dereference single pointer you will get value that is not address. This is why ı confuse. This sitiuation broke this rule. If ıt would be double pointer ı could expect address not an value

Comment: Read what I said more fully, especially the last sentence.  Yes, dereferencing `p` gets you a value that not an address, but rather an array.  But what do you think happens *next*?  An array is not the same thing as its first element -- not even if it has only one element.  Data types are important.

Comment: To get `a[0]` you must first dereference `p` **before** applying `[0]`. Try `(*p)[0]`

Comment: @JohnBollinger   It doesn’t fit into dereferencing definition. It is holding address and when you dereference it you should get content of address. Not a itself of address.But ı ı can accept it as exception with looking for data type. What would be drawingbacks if compiler handle it like as single pointer? Answer of this will be my result.

Comment: It absolutely fits, @KaruF.  When you dereference a pointer to an array, the result is an array.  Nothing strange about that at all.  Where you seem to be getting confused is what happens when a value of array type appears in an expression.  In most cases, it is automatically converted to a pointer to the first array element -- this is the norm, not an exception (though there *are* a couple of exceptions, among them when an lvalue of array type is the operand of unary `&`).  As I said earlier, the same would apply if you used `a` in place of `*p`.

Comment: Please, edit the question to add the actual output you get, and also the output you expect, instead.  This way, everybody has a clear idea of what you mean.

Comment: @JohnBollinger  After some day, ı have been researching a thing that ı didn't get exactly and suddenly ı got you what you mean. Actually it helped to me to getting other answer of question. If you leave answer ı am going to mark it as result. Thanks at all...

Comment: @KaruF, LuisColorado already wrote that answer.  I have nothing to add to what he said.  You have several good answers, but if this were my question, Luis's is the one I would accept.

Comment: You deleted your last question while I was writing a comment, so here it is: *"Does synthesized move ctor use move ctor of int?"* Yes, but moving an `int` is same as copying it. (Also, to nitpick: `int` isn't a class, so it can't have constructors, so it's better to say that it "moves and `int`", or something like that. Also, the word "syntheize" usually means something else (related to compiler generating `!=` from a custom `==`, and so on), so I prefer "implicitly generated".)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Ah, thanks for your attention. In fact post was canceled by SO and then ı decided to delete. I think ı have problem with rvalue references and move semantics. It would be great to discuss those topic and getting chance to ask my questions one by one. Isn't allowed it by SO? Maybe you can help me about it?

Comment: @KaruF *"Maybe you can help me about it?"* What do you mean? If SO is too strict for you (or your questions are too basic), you can try asking [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116940/c-questions-and-answers) or on [reddit](https://old.reddit.com/r/cpp_questions/).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yeah that room could be great for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int a[10] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
int (*p)[10]; // ı know it is pointer to int array that consist of 10 elements.
int *d;

d = a;
```

Here, `d` is a pointer to an array element, the first element of `a`.  The asignment is correct as `a` by itself in an expression means precisely that, *the address of the first element.*

```
p = &a; // it is array type
```

Here, you assign the address of `a` array to `p` (this is a pointer to an array of 10 `int` elements, so the assignment is correct, both pointers point to arrays of 10 `int`s) so `p` is *almost* an alias of `a`.  But `p` is still a pointer to an array (so it stores an address) while `a` is not.  `a` is an array that has ten integeres, not a pointer.

```
printf("*p = %p , p = %d", (void *)*p, (void*)p); // it prints same thing, start address of "a" array
```

here, `p` is a pointer to an array, so `*p` is, itself an array, and, as when an array appears in an expression, it is interpreted as the address of the first element, it is indeed equivalent to `&p[0]` which is a pointer to an `int`, pointing to the first element of the array.  In the case of plain `p`, you convert the pointer to the array into a `void *` pointer, and pass it to the `printf()` routine, getting the same value (the array starts at its first element, so both values should be equal, but in this case you are printing the address of the array, and not the address of the first element)  I know this is strange, but you can never use an array in an expression, so when an expression results in an array as a whole, the compiler generates code to extract the address of the first element, instead.

```
printf("*d = %d, d = %p",*d,d); // it prints a[0] and start address of a respectively.
```

in this case, `d` is a pointer to int, that has been initialized to the start of the array `a`.  So `*d` is the actual element pointed to by `d`, you get *the array cell value* and not the address of the first element (this should be `0`, but try to change the array cells in the initialization to confirm).  You convert it to `void *` (which results in Undefined Behaviour, so the actual value can be 0 or different, don't mind about it) and print it.  Of course, `d` is the pointer value, if you convert it to `void *` and pass it to `printf()` you will get the virtual address of `a`, again.

You should take into account several things:

- **An array and a pointer are not the same thing.**  To address (through `p`) the integer values of the array pointed to by `p` you need two dereferences (the first when you access the array through the pointer `p` and the second after doing the needed pointer arithmetic to get the offset of the array element.  But `d` is just a plain pointer to `int` which you cannot derreference twice, and the compiler won't)
- An implicit dereference happens when you name an array (directly or indirectly, as the result of some subexpression evaluation) and is used as such.  You don't show the results of your code, but, (I have neither done too, my apologies for that)  IMHO, you lack (in your mind) some dereference at some point in the process (probably the one I'm talking about above)... arrays can be accesed, but cannot be used as variables, you cannot pass them by value, you cannot sort them (except by some routine that knows the internal structure of the array, and passing it the pointer to the first element that represents its name alone) You cannot assign arrays as a whole, because you cannot use an array in C.  You can solve the evaluation, by analysing the types of the subexpressions you evaluate, as below:
- When you evaluate `*p`, you obtain an array (because `p` is defined as a pointer to an array of 10 elements), so immediately the compiler builds a pointer to that array's first element (the compiler is doing two dereferences here, in a single shot) making indeed it to be semantically the same as `&a[0]`.  You can do the conversion in two steps... knowing that `p` points to `a`.  You first change `*p` for `a`, then `a` by `&a[0]`.  When you evaluate `*d`, you are evaluating a pointer to `int` (which is actually pointing to the first element of `a` and dereferencing, so you actually obtain the array cell content, which is a plain integer.  There are not such two dereferences in that case, but just the one you specify.

If you take off all the casts, you will probably see only one warning in the expression `*d` not matching a pointer, as it is an integer.  This is a GCC extension to help you identify errors, as the passed value is actually not a pointer and the matching format specifier in the format string requires actually a pointer.

Answer (score 2):

Because `p` has type `int (*)[10]` i.e. pointer to array of size 10, the dereferenced `p`, has type `int[10]` i.e. array of size 10.  That array type is being passed as a parameter to a function, causing the array to decay to a pointer to its first member with a resulting type of `int *`.

So what this line is telling you:

```
printf("*p = %p , p = %d", (void *)*p, (void*)p);
```

Is that the address of the array itself is the same as the address of its first member.

Comment: Rather: it is telling you that the array pointer contains the address of the array.

Answer (score 1):

All of the following have the very same address:

- The array, `a`.
- The first item in the array, `&a[0]`
- The value of a pointer pointing at the first item in the array. `d`
- The value of a pointer pointing at the array. `p`

When you dereference `p` you get the array `a`. Which behaves like any array: whenever used in an expression it "decays" into a pointer to its first element.

> When ı dereference "p", ı expect "a[0]"

That is wrong. In order to do that you would have do dereference twice, `**p`.

Comment: So ı searched about that and it shouldn’t be ı think. But we can say it p is a double pointer or acting like that?

Comment: @KaruF "But we can say it p is a double pointer" No.  "or acting like that?" No.

Comment: `a` is not the array, but when appearing in an expression it states for the address of the first element of array `a`.  There's no way of using an array as an whole object in C.  So said, `a` and `&a[0]` are exactly the same pointer (and typed as a pointer to an array element's type), semantically, while `&a` is typed differently (as a pointer to an array of 10 `int`s)

Comment: You have forgot `&a` which is an interesting point, because despite of having the same value in most implementations as `a`, it is typed differently, as a pointer to an array type.

Comment: @LuisColorado Of course `a` is the array. That it decays in most expressions is another story. And you can use it as a whole object just fine or otherwise `&a + 1` wouldn't point at the next array of a potential array of arrays. `p` and `&a` are identical in the original code.

Comment: It doesn't decay.  An array name in an expression (except when it's preceded by the `&` operator) is always interpreted as the address of it's first element, so the array name as an expression is exactly equivalent as `&a[0]` and not the array itself.  Array decayment is only used when considering parameter declarations and happens only at the first (most external) level of the array, and happens statically.

Comment: @LuisColorado "Decay" is not a formal term. The complete and formal definition is in C17 6.3.2.1 §3: "Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator, or the unary `&` operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has type ‘‘array of type’’ is converted to an expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’ that points to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue." "Decay" might also refer to function parameter adjustment (6.7.6.3). These two different rules are "harmonized" with each other, so that function args and parameters match.

Comment: @LuisColorado For example `unsigned char* p = (unsigned char*)a + sizeof(a) - n;` is valid and well-defined C. The first use of `a` does decay into a pointer to the first element (but that doesn't matter here), the second use of `a` does not decay. In each case `a` is of course an array and nothing else.

Comment: I repeat, decayment is not a type conversion, but a type change that is done in the declaration of a function parameter (and only on a function parameter) to allow for unbounded array processing.  The Compiler interprets your data and *changes* the  declaration itself to define a pointer instead of an array.  This happens only at a first level of a multilevel array.  And is a very special issue in the C language.

Comment: @LuisColorado I just literally quoted the C standard which says otherwise. No point in arguing further.

Comment: You didn't quote the standard... you just made an interpretation (your interpretation) of a quote of the standard.  As you don't give the reference, of course, it's impossible to debate or argument.

Comment: "an expression that has type ‘‘array of type’’ is converted to an expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’" Is an exact quote from the standard. Then you respond to that by saying that no conversion takes place. The chapter reference is right there for those who could be arsed to actually read the comment. Notably, your own comments are however 100% subjective opinions with no sources.

Answer (score 1):

One more thing about "pointer vs pointer to array".

In your example "p" points to entire array. If you perform pointer incrementation/decrementation - it will point to the first address after the array i.e. every time when you perform the same operation - it will move with int*10 bytes = 40 bytes further, compared to current address it points to (in your example).

On the other hand you have "d" which is regular pointer - it increments/decrements with as that much bytes, as the data type size it belongs to is.

Especially "d" is redundant, since the array itself is a pointer. If you remove the "[]" bracets, you can apply "*" dereferencing operator directly to the array name, to extract the value which is stored to the address it points to. You can replace the "[]" bracets with pointer arithmetic to traverse the array.

Comment: Yes it is. Thanks for your reply amd ı understood that very well at my before research. I guess the caption that ı put it direct you wrong way but this is not my question. I wonder why compiler acts like that? What would be drawingbacks if compiler handle it like as single pointer?

Comment: ***Arrays are not pointers***.  They are automatically *converted to* pointers in many contexts, but not in certain others, such as when they are operands of the `sizeof` or unary `&`  operator.  The automatic conversion is why you can apply `*` to arrays, and also why you can apply `[]` to arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Some additional issues not yet covered:

**Specifier mismatch**

Do not print an `int` with `"%p"` and risk *undefined behavior* (UB).
Enable all warnings and use a matching specifier.

```
int *d;
...
// printf("*d = %p, d = %p",*d,d);
printf("*d = %d, d = %p",*d,d);
```

**Advanced: Equivalent, not certainly the same bit pattern**

*Someway compiler handle it and returns address data of "a" array.*

```
printf("*p = %p , p = %d", (void *)*p, (void*)p);
```

The `*p` and `p` are both pointers, yet of different types.
`p` is the address of the array `a`.
`*p` is the address of the array element `a[0]`, the address of an `int`.

Even after casting to `void *`, the results may have a different bit pattern.
Yet `(void *)*p == (void*)p` is still true.

Comment: Thanks for editing ı missed it unintentionally.

Comment: @KaruF The real mistake was not _missing it_, but not enabling all compiler warnings.  Save time, enable all warnings.  (note: changing code after answers arrive is poor SO etiquette - consider a _rollback_.)

Comment: I didn't know it. Thanks for warning.